# How do you check if two strings are in the same order at any point in the string?

Tags: python, string, slice

```
["word", "ordw"] = True
["word", "odrw"] = False
```

How do you use slicing to get this result?

Comment: I assume you're checking against `ord` in the above example? Otherwise I can't see how you could produce the results expected.

Comment: `if word in check*2:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple brute-force O(n^2) solution:

```
>>> def same_cyclic(w1, w2):
...     return any(w1 == w2[i:] + w2[:i] for i in range(len(w2)))
... 
>>> same_cyclic("word", "ordw")
True
>>> same_cyclic("word", "odrw")
False
```

Optimizing it would be the interesting part -- if there's at least one unique letter in the word, you can get it down to O(n) by just rotating to make that one letter line up and doing a single comparison.

For the general case, I guess I'd use a `Counter` to find the *most* unique letter, and then try one permutation per times that letter appears, which should account for all the possible ways the two words could line up.  That'd have a time complexity of O(m*n) where *m* is the number of occurrences of the least-frequently occurring letter.